# counting occurrences in a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I can't get a method that counts the number of occurrences of a pair in a list

for example if the input is `["the","man","is","the","man","."]` then the output should be `[(("man","is"),1),(("is","the"),1),(("the","man"),2),(("man","."),1)]`

putting into consideration that I already made a function that divides the list into pairs and a method that counts the number of occurrences of a pair, but I can't get the output needed

the `countHelper` method counts the number of occurrences in a list, but i can't add it after the pair

```
helper [] =[]
helper [x] =[]
helper (x1:(x2:xs)) = (x1,x2): helper  (x2:xs)

countHelper [] _= 0
countHelper ((x1,x2):xs) count =  
   if (x1,x2) `elem` xs then 1 + countHelper xs count
                        else 0 + countHelper xs count
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that?

Comment: countHelper [] _= 0
countHelper ((x1,x2):xs) count =  if (x1,x2) `elem` xs then 1 + countHelper xs count
                                                     
               else 0 + countHelper xs count

Comment: i want a function that adds the output of counthelper to the list of pairs

Comment: @ReemAyman please put your work in the question section, formatted. Thank you.

Comment: show us you tried OR ELSE, you dont even want to know what were going to do to you. :)

Comment: helper [] =[]
helper [x] =[]
helper (x1:(x2:xs)) = (x1,x2): helper  (x2:xs)




countHelper [] _= 0
countHelper ((x1,x2):xs) count =  if (x1,x2) `elem` xs then 1 + countHelper xs count
                                                     
               else 0 + countHelper xs count

Answer (score 1):

step by step...

write an ngram function

```
ngram (x:y:xs) = (x,y):ngram (y:xs)
ngram _        = []
```

sort the resulting list, group same elements together, extract the element and count into a pair, alltogether

```
map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group . sort . ngram
```

I'm not sure the order is well defined in the question, this will be alphabethical.